# System Modeling and Simulation

Tags: system-modeler, system-modeling

MMA version 14 Windows 10

I am trying to learn to simulate a model. I start with built in models like:

```
mods=SystemModelExamples["Models", "*Physics*"]
```

I e.g. pick the bouncing ball:

```
mod= mods[[3]]
```

Then I try to simulate this model:

```
sim = SystemModelSimulate[mod]
```

and get the following error messages:

```
SystemModelSimulate::bld: Failed to build model EducationExamples.Physics.BouncingBalls.BouncingBalls2D.

SystemModelSimulate::bldl: Error: <<10414>>
```

Now I am stuck. Has anybody an idea what goes wrong here?

Comment: For me, it [works normally](https://i.imgur.com/497ude8.png) both in Wolfram Cloud (v14) and in v13.3 on Windows ...

Comment: Worked for me on `"14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"`

Comment: Restarting MMA gives the same error with an error  number that is each time larger.

Comment: @Daniel Huber: With my MAC Studio M1 Max with 64 GB, I have no problem and do not get any error message. MMA version 13.1.

Comment: Can you simulate a simpler model, such as SystemModels["IntroductoryExamples.HelloWorld"]? That will check if something is wrong with the simulator setup, perhaps requiring restart Mathematica with reset. Can you get properties of the model, e.g., mod["StateVariables"]?

Comment: @tad `mod = SystemModels["IntroductoryExamples.HelloWorld"]` seems to work. However, `sim = SystemModelSimulate[mod]` simply returns the input. Similar with `mod["StateVariables"]`

Comment: The you start a fresh session, the first time you run a system model command, do you see a progress box under the input saying it is starting system modeler? If not, likely something wrong with your setup. Perhaps a bad cache. Try reset Mathematica -- see troubleshooting in the Documentation. If that doesn't help, try Wolfram support.

Comment: @DanielHuber I got a similar error message in MMA `14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)`. The StackTrace reported following fatal error: `LINK : fatal error LNK1158: "rc.exe" kann nicht ausgeführt werden`. Adding the folder containing the rc.exe `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\vc15\SDK\bin\` to the PATH environment variable fixed the issue in my case.

Comment: @tad and  Yes, I see the progress box.

Comment: @vindobona  The "c:\Program Files\..." folder does not exists on my machine. However I found an "rc.exe" in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\rc.exe" and put this on the path without success.

Comment: It looks like this is some idiosyncratic problem with your computer or installation. You could try resetting/reinstalling Mathematica, or contact Wolfram Support.